# How to get the location coordinate based on nickname

Tags: uber-api

I am using the [uber sdk for iOS](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk). And i see I have to specify the

```
button.setProductID("abc123-productID")
button.setPickupLocation(latitude: "37.770", longitude: "-122.466", nickname: "California Academy of Sciences")
button.setDropoffLocation(latitude: "37.791", longitude: "-122.405", nickname: "Pier 39")
```

How can I get the coordinate information based on the location's nickname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS Uber SDK doesn't provide this functionality. However, Apple's CoreLocation framework has the CLGeocoder class that provides both forward-geocoding and reverse-geocoding. To convert an address into coordinates to pass to the request button, you can use the function `geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:`.